# Pass parameters through URL in C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code for a Button click event where I open a new Tab for a Report and I need to pass a parameter to that from the code behind,

```
String classname = txt_classname.SelectedValue;
String teachername = "Some name";


string url = "Report_Classwise.aspx";
string s = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
```

I need to pass classname & teachername to Report_Classwise.aspx page, I have tried setting

```
string url = "Report_Classwise.aspx?classname='"+classname+"'&teachername='"+teachername+"'";
```

But it didn't work

Comment: what do you mean by "it didn't work"? If you are accessing the parameters on server, then Request.QueryString e.g. Request.QueryString["classname"] should get you the parameter value.

Comment: It didn't open the tab/window

Comment: your javascript will be invalid as url contains single quote which is used to wrap url as string in window.open function. Rashmin's answer should solve the issue. Check the browser console for errors though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You dont need to add additional single quote in URL

```
string url = "Report_Classwise.aspx?classname=" + classname + "&teachername=" 
+ teachername;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, But in the URL it says there were so many 20%20%20% in between classname and teachername, is it normal?

Comment: %20 is an encoded form of ' ' (space character), try to trim the string

Answer (score 3):

You single quotes might interfere with your parameter names, are you sure you really want to have them there?

You might want to encode your parameters to make sure that they don't contain some special characters etc, and drop your single quotes:

```
string url = "Report_Classwise.aspx?classname=" + encodeURIComponent(classname) +"&teachername=" + ncodeURIComponent(teachername);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use string.Format for more readability and avoid confusions.

```
string url = string.Format("Report_Classwise.aspx?classname={0}&teachername={1}", classname, teachername);
```